# Find String Between To Identical Control Separators?

Tags: c#, regex, special-characters

I'm reading from a file, and need to find a string that is encapsulated by two identical non-ascii values/control seperators, in this case 'RS'

[image: Image in Notepad++]

How would I go about doing this? Would I need some form of regex?

Comment: Scan through the file until you find the separator,  then read until the next separator, then stop.

Comment: Does this file have more than one occurrence of this string and separators?

Comment: It is strange that you call Record Separator ␞ both non-ASCII and a field encapsulation (by which, I think you take as quoting). It is ASCII and I would think it is being used as a field _separator._ A few things to clarify: 1) What encoding is the file? 2) ␞ is also a Unicode character so you will see it the string that you read the file contents into. 3) Can you exclude the possibility that an ␞ character could be part of a field's data? If not, what strategy was used to distinguish ␞ as a separator and ␞ as data? (Ref: [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules))

Comment: @Ryan, did you try any of the solutions posted here?

Comment: None of them seemed to have worked so far. I'm searching for a solution at the moment.

Comment: But you haven't replied to my question. If you are more specific in how that input string is, we can give you working solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RS` stands for Record Separator, and it has a value of 30 (or 0x1E in hexadecimal). You can use this regular expression:

```
\x1E([\w\s]*?)\x1E
```

That matches the RS, then matches any letter, number or space, and then again the RS. The `?` is to make the regex match as less characters as possible, in case there are more RS characters afterwards.

If you prefer not to match numbers, you could use `[a-zA-Z\s]` instead of `[\w\s]`.

Example:

```
string fileContents = "Something \u001Eyour string\u001E more things \u001Eanother text\u001E end.";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(fileContents, @"\x1E([\w\s]*?)\x1E");

if (matches.Count == 0)
    return; // Not found, display an error message and exit.

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    if (match.Groups.Count > 1)
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

As you can see, you get a collection of `Match`, and each `match.Value` will have the whole matched string including the separators. `match.Groups` will have all matched groups, being the first one again the whole matched string (that's by default) and then each of your groups (those between parenthesis). In this case, you only have one in your regex, so you just need the second one on that list.

Comment: This seems to work, except that the record separator appears four times in the line. It only gets the last pair, and skips the first pair of separators.

Comment: Well, you only specified that you wanted to find **a** string, not many. More details about your scenario, better solutions. :)

Comment: My apologies - in hindsight my question wasn't as clear as it should've been

Answer (score 0):

Using regex you can do something like this:

```
string pattern = string.Format("{0}(.*){1}",firstString,secondString);
var matches = Regex.Matches(myString, pattern);
foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        foreach (Capture capture in match.Captures)
        {
        //Do stuff, with the current you should remove firstString and secondString from the capture.Value
        }
    }
```

After that use [Regex.match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) to find the string that match with the pattern built before.
Remember to escape all the special char for regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Regex.Matches`, I'm using `X` as the separator in this example:

```
var fileContents = "Xsomething1X Xsomething2X Xsomething3X";

var results = Regex.Matches(fileContents, @"(X).*?(\1)");
```

The you can loop on `results` to do anything you want with the matches.

The `\1` in the regex means "reference first group". I've put `X` between `()` so it is going to be group 1, the I use `\1` to say that the match in this place should be exactly the same as the group 1.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regular expression for that.

1. Read the contents of the file (`File.ReadAllText`).
2. Split on the separator character (`String.Split`).
3. If you know there's only one occurrence of your string, take the second array element (`result[1]`). Otherwise, take every other entry (`result.Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 1)`).